# How to Customize the Google oauth authorization error window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-signin

I use google Oauth for login. Access to the right account will be implemented well. However, if it is an incorrect approach, an error window will appear.

like this

'Authorization Error
Error 403: org_internal
This client is restricted to users within its organization.'

I want to customize that window.

I tried to include alert('error') like this.

```
gauth.signIn({
            scope : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
          }).then(function(){
              checkLoginStatus();
          },function(){
              alert('error');
          });
```

But, it appears after the appearing error window.
I want to hide the error window.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "It appears after the appearing error window. I want to hide the error window". Your question sounds like a general JavaScript question rather than Google Sign-In specific.

However, from what I read in your question I imagine you want to restrict your customers to be within the organization. In that case you can add `hosted_domain` to restrict the organization. Or if you already know the user's email address to sign-in with, use `login_hint` to specify the username.

You may find those options here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2clientconfig

Hope this helps.